# Dice Probability of rolling at least one four?

Tags: probability, statistics

One dice is rolled three times. What is the probability of getting at least **one** four?

I've been getting stuck on what to do next
I know that it could be one four, two fours, or all three rolls could be fours.
I just don't know which probability to use 1/216, 5/216, or 25/216? Or if any of those are correct?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider updating your question with some information about what you have tried or where you are getting stuck. You will find people are much more willing to help if you do!

Comment: Consider the negative probability space:  what is the probability of getting no fours on three consecutive rolls?

Answer (score 6):

What is the probability $p$ to get no 4 at all?

$1 - p $ is your answer.

Comment: p=5/6? So the answer would be 1-(5/6) so 1/6?

Comment: I mean no 4 at all during the 3 attempts.

Comment: (5/6)^3=p then it would be 1-(5/6)^3=91/216?

Comment: @Megan:  That is correct.

Comment: @mookid Thanks so much!